# Unable to install PHP on Mac OS Mavericks using Homebrew

Tags: php, macos, laravel, homebrew

I'm pretty noob in terminal, so I wanted to start learning PHP and Laravel 4, and I have set up Apache server and installed Homebrew to install all other packages of PHP and composted and so on, but when I'm trying to install PHP on Homebrew, I always get an error:

This is the command I tried to install with:

```
brew install php53
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libs/libphp5.bundle] Error 1

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/homebrew):
https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/issues

/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:319:in `rescue in open': uninitialized constant     
   GitHub::OpenSSL (NameError)
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:304:in `open'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:345:in `issues_matching'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:373:in `issues_for_formula'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:171:in `fetch_issues'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:167:in `issues'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:208:in `dump'
from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:133:in `rescue in <main>'
from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:72:in `<main>'
```

I always run `brew doctor`:

```
brew doctor
```

Which produces the following warning:

> Warning: You have an outdated version of /usr/bin/install_name_tool
>   installed. This will cause binary package installations to fail. This
>   can happen if you install osx-gcc-installer or RailsInstaller. To
>   restore it, you must reinstall OS X or restore the binary from the OS
>   packages.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried... reinstalling OS X or restoring the binary from the OS packages...?

Comment: Mmmmm....PHP 5.4.17 is loaded in the latest preview of OSX 10.9 Mavericks and needs to be turned on by uncommenting a line in the httpd.conf file...uncomment this line LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

Comment: My advice is - use vagrant. As for me - it is easiest way to setup work environment. You can start with something like https://puphpet.com/ . Or you can use http://laravel.com/docs/homestead

Answer (score 0):

It seems like others have had this issue. One suggestion was to use

```
xcode-select --install
```

I found that here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1172

Comment: i had already download it and installed it but it doesn't work !!

Comment: I just use WAMP. Vagrant does seem to be a very easy solution though. http://www.vagrantup.com

Answer (score 0):

If you've only just installed xcode tools, you might also be getting an earlier error stating that you haven't accepted xcode's license requirements. Try entering the command:

```
xcodebuild -license
```

and follow the instructions to accept the xcode T&C.